# Oracle JDeveloper, JSF include javascript

Tags: jquery, oracle, jsf, jdeveloper

I'm using oracle jdeveloper 11g, using JSF.  I need to include jquery file.
My question is how i can include javascript files and css files into jspx

thanks,
Adrian Rodriguez

Comment: I assume you are not using ADF ? it is different a bit with ADF.

Answer (score 0):

Include them just like you would in HTML.  Use jsp params if you need a dynamic path to your copy of jquery.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Of you can place the same call in a jsp include keep your client side calls in one spot.